# ng generate component in subdirectory

Tags: angular-cli, angular5, ng-generate

I have the following directory structure

[image]

I would like to create a new page, let's say, an About page.
I want to put it in src/app/page/about/*

So I try:

```
ng generate component pages/about
```

but I get this error:

```
Error: More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module.
More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module.
```

Is it a good idea to use pages to store my separate pages?
How can I generate components in a subdirectory using the angular-cli?

Comment: Obviously, I can manually move them after generating them, but it would be nice to be able to skip that manual step

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Because there are 2 modules (`app.module.ts`, `shared.module.ts`) found the CLI does not know which module to declare your component in. To get around this you have to tell the CLI which module you wish to declare your component in with the `module` option

```
ng generate component pages/about --module=app.module
// or
ng generate component pages/about --module=shared.module
```

Comment: You don't need to include the `.module` after the module name.

Answer (score 9):

To create a component as part of any new module you could also do :

```
cd newModule to change directory into the newModule folder

ng g c newComponent to create a component as a child of the module.
```

This worked out for me. I was getting same error as you received.

Answer (score 3):

**Specify Your Module**

You have two modules and haven't specified which one you want to add the new component to.

If you want to add it to your `app` module, you can use simply:

```
ng generate component pages/about --module=app
```

And likewise to add it to your `shared` module, you can use:

```
ng generate component pages/about --module=shared
```

With shorthand, these commands can be shortened to:

```
ng g c pages/about --module=app
ng g c pages/about --module=shared
```

Your file structure looks off too. I would recommend moving all of the files in the `pages` directory up one step to the `app` directory.

Answer (score 2):

In general, there is need to generate component in a particular path or not more than one parent module like the above case.

```
$> ng g component path/component-name  
  <enter>
```

No need of src/app/path/component-name ->path, if it is an Angular app.
If you mention src/app, then this error occurs.

```
"Error: More than one module matches. Use skip-import "
```