# --skip-import not working while generating components with more than one module

Tags: angular, angular-cli

So i'm facing this weird issue. I have 5 modules with routing modules in my angular app. I'm trying to create a component say in fifth module using the command. In the folder i'm trying to create the component i deleted the routing module so that the closest module is the one in which it should import. It works fine as it finds the closest module but it should not do it when --skip-import flag is present but it does so.

```
ng g c path/to/component/name --skip-import
```

But i get the error

> Error: More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module.
>   More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module.

I tried use the --module flag to specify the module but still got the same error. Have used both earlier with success.

In the second case i have 2 modules and tried creating a component it creates successfully but imports to closest module even if the `--skip-import` flag is present.

[Angular CLI Docs for generating component](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-component)

Below are the screenshots for the same.

[image: --skip-import present still imports]

[image: Error When --module flag is specified]

Is it something i'm doing wrong or is it a bug? Struggling with this from almost an hours trying ever if and but with no luck.

Referred these questions already. But no luck

[Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46174863/error-more-than-one-module-matches-use-skip-import-option-to-skip-importing-th)
[Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102863/ng-generate-component-in-subdirectory)

My @angular version details

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.10",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.5",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "g": "^2.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^5.2.4",
    "ng-pick-datetime-moment": "^1.0.5",
    "ngx-pagination-bootstrap": "^1.5.0",
    "ngx-select-dropdown": "^0.2.1",
    "ngx-slides": "^1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.10",
    "tether": "^1.4.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.106",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "gh-pages": "^1.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though i'm responding to this a bit late. 
But here is the solution(s) that can work and the one that worked for me.

1. Make sure angular is added to the environmental paths. Here is a post that can help you  [(add angular to environment variables)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227794/ng-command-not-found-while-creating-new-project-using-angular-cli)
2. Make the version on angular and angular-cli both global and local are compatible
3. Try clearing your npm cache and run `npm install` again
4. If none of the above works the lat resort is uninstall angular and angular-cli completely and try a re-install.

The last one solved it for me but others also come handy as have helped other colleagues solve similar issues with either of the first three steps.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

You should run generate it with this. It will generate the folder and component for you.

```
ng generate component folder_name --module app
```